# Anaconda Spyder fails to start because of Jedi problems

Tags: anaconda, spyder

> File
>   "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/introspection/manager.py",
>   line 220, in get_completions
>       info = self._get_code_info('completions', automatic=automatic)   File
>   "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/introspection/manager.py",
>   line 216, in _get_code_info
>       **kwargs)   File "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/introspection/utils.py",
>   line 75, in **init**
>       self._get_info()   File "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/introspection/utils.py",
>   line 87, in _get_info
>       lexer = find_lexer_for_filename(self.filename)   File "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/introspection/utils.py",
>   line 180, in find_lexer_for_filename
>       lexer = get_lexer_for_filename(filename)   File "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygments/lexers/**init**.py",
>   line 203, in get_lexer_for_filename
>       res = find_lexer_class_for_filename(_fn, code)   File "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygments/lexers/**init**.py",
>   line 168, in find_lexer_class_for_filename
>       for cls in find_plugin_lexers():   File "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygments/plugin.py",
>   line 53, in find_plugin_lexers
>       yield entrypoint.load()   File "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2404, in load
>       self.require(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2427, in require
>       items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)   File
>   "/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 872, in resolve
>       raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req) pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (parso 0.1.1
>   (/home/srikanth/anaconda3/envs/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages),
>   Requirement.parse('parso==0.1.0'), {'jedi'})

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run in a system terminal (cmd.exe)

```
conda update jedi
```

to fix this. If that fails, then please run

```
conda install parso=0.1.0
```

Comment: Good to know! Please mark my answer as correct by selecting the green check mark above. Thanks!